# delimeter search in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my database i have rows with a column called as salts. the salts columns has different entries as a+b+c , b+a+c , a+c+b ....

what i want to do is.. i try to search for salts which have a+b+c irrespective of the occurence of the alphabets..

Example : even when i search for a+b+c i should get b+a+c and a+c+b as their output..

Simple sql SELECT command tried is :

```
$salt = "a+b+c";
select * from tableName where salt = '$salt';
```

From the above query i get only rows which have entry as a+b+c and not b+a+c or c+a+b..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_data` WHERE MATCH (`salt`)
AGAINST ('+Ambroxol +Levocetirizine' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by `Regular Expression` like below:

```
select * from tableName where salt REGEXP '[a-c]\\+[a-c]\\+[a-c]';
```

In case of your comment(`a+b+c+d+e+f`):

```
    select * from tableName where salt REGEXP '[a-f]{1}\\+[a-f]{1}$';
```

Comment: what if there are a+b+c+d+e+f combinations.. how would the query be?

Comment: by this we restrict or query to only that alphabet... ali+masudian+pour && masudian+pour+ali && pour+masudian+ali... what now?

Comment: @user2740034 Just replace `[a-f]` to `[a-z]` :)

Comment: @user2740034 And also remove the limitation `{1}`

Answer (score 0):

If it's only those combinations you are after, you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE 
  (salt LIKE '%a+b+c%' OR
  salt LIKE '%a+c+b%' OR
  salt LIKE '%b+a+c%' OR
  salt LIKE '%b+c+a%' OR
  salt LIKE '%c+b+a%' OR
  salt LIKE '%c+a+b%')
```

Or if you need a case insensitive match,

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE 
  (LCASE(salt) LIKE '%a+b+c%' OR
  LCASE(salt) LIKE '%a+c+b%' OR
  LCASE(salt) LIKE '%b+a+c%' OR
  LCASE(salt) LIKE '%b+c+a%' OR
  LCASE(salt) LIKE '%c+b+a%' OR
  LCASE(salt) LIKE '%c+a+b%')
```

This should work, although performance may not be great.